# iPhone: Detecting a replicated sound of particular frequency (amplitude)

Tags: iphone, audio

I am trying to write an iPhone App that should monitor the any incoming sound. I am not sure how can I get the sound recorded by iPhone's Microphone and detect its frequency. If same frequency sound repeated couple of times then I need to take some action. Could anyone please help me here. I went through the [How to detect sound frequency / pitch on an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696773/how-to-detect-sound-frequency-pitch-on-an-iphone) but I couldn't understood how to use them.

Any documentation or example would be really useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll appreciate reading [this](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/), on how to get the sound "without having to drop down to C", by using [AVAudioRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)...

Then, begin researching [FFT](http://www.relisoft.com/science/physics/sound.html)...

Checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592345/do-you-know-a-good-and-efficient-fft) about FFT for iPhone, which mentions various options, including the possibility of using Apple's [Accelerate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/AccelerateFrameworkData/_index.html) framework (in which you will need to drop to C) to apparently get "Apple-written FFT functions".

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework) is probably what you really want to read.

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the links.

Comment: Thanks. The links contain everything I need.